# Setup Openframework in Codeblock in Windows

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks, openframeworks

I would like to configure OpenFramework IDE in my codeblock. I want to build an app which prints the line on screen.

Comment: You've mentioned in a comment that you want to draw graphs, that would be good to mention in the question. Aside from that this is far too broad - have you tried anything?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only thing you want is to just print a line of text you can use std::cout that prints to basic output onto your console window when the application runs. This is the most basic and easiest way to solve this.

If need to do something more complex than that, like program with GUI instead of console app, I would suggest you to use something other than OpenFrameworks, like f.e. Qt, that has a support for things like this. OpenFrameworks has the capability of doing all that, it just isn't it's main goal. You can download various addons that implement things like UI elemenets, but they are usually pretty simple.

**Edit:** I've just realized that by line you probably didn't mean a line of text...

Well, OpenFrameworks has no longer an Code Blocks support, you can still though download an older version from http://openframeworks.cc/download/older/

Comment: thanks Maros for your reply but i have to plugin Openframework in my codeblock so that I can make a project and draw graphs by using Openfrmewrok, just i need steps how i can all set it up

Comment: Thanks Maros for your great help, i downloaded the older version that support codeblock, kindly also mention how i can configure it with my codeblock and able to build my first simple application on it.

Comment: Marking the correct answer and upvoting would be appreciated. And if there was no official guide on how to install it, you should find one fairly simple online.